# How to push screen a full screen in the subtree of StatefulShellBranch

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

How can I push the detail screen in '/c' in the code below to fill the screen?
(not inside the bottom navigation bar)

I know that I can declare the detail route outside of the **StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack** widget.
However, my purpose is to inject the state with BlocProvider in **ScaffoldWithNavBar** and display the screen as a full screen so that the state injected in ScaffoldWithNavBar can be used.

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _rootNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'root');

final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
    initialLocation: '/a',
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state,
            StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell) {

                  // **Inject Bloc!!**
          return ScaffoldWithNavBar(navigationShell: navigationShell);
        },
        branches: <StatefulShellBranch>[
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _sectionANavigatorKey,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: '/a',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const RootScreen(label: 'A', detailsPath: '/a/details'),
                routes: <RouteBase>[
                  GoRoute(
                    path: 'details',
                    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                        const DetailsScreen(label: 'A'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),

          StatefulShellBranch(
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: '/b',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const RootScreen(
                  label: 'B',
                  detailsPath: '/b/details/1',
                  secondDetailsPath: '/b/details/2',
                ),
                routes: <RouteBase>[
                  GoRoute(
                    path: 'details/:param',
                    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                        DetailsScreen(
                      label: 'B',
                      param: state.pathParameters['param'],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),

          StatefulShellBranch(
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: '/c',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const RootScreen(
                  label: 'C',
                  detailsPath: '/c/details',
                ),
                routes: <RouteBase>[
                  GoRoute(
                    path: 'details',
                    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                        DetailsScreen(
                      label: 'C',
                      extra: state.extra,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),


            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
```

++ How to push screen a full screen in the subtree of StatefulShellBranch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the easiest way to push a page to full screen and to "ignore" the shell is to use the parentNavigatorKey parameter in your GoRoute and to assign it the root navigator key :

```
GoRoute(
  path: 'details',
  parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
    DetailsScreen(
      label: 'C',
      extra: state.extra,
    ),
  ),
```

This allows you to bypass the default navigator for this GoRoute, which is the one automatically generated for this branch of the statefulshell.

> A separate Navigator will be built for each StatefulShellBranch in a StatefulShellRoute, and the routes of this branch will be placed onto that Navigator instead of the root Navigator.

[StatefulShell Branch documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/StatefulShellBranch-class.html#:%7E:text=A%20separate%20Navigator%20will%20be,instead%20of%20the%20root%20Navigator.)

You can then call context.go or context.push like you normally do.

Comment: That way, DetailScreen will be a subtree of the MaterialApp. 
What I want is if it can be a subtree of the RootScreen with fullscreen.
But I don't think that's possible :(

Comment: this solution doesn't work, because every link you open from there will in the root, and is not desired effect. I have the same issue